# VirtualBox: deny internet access to a Guest Machine

Tags: virtualbox

I would like to create a guest system that is completely separated from the host system AND the internet (no internet connection--nothing can go out, nothing can go in). Is this possible?

My host system is Windows 10 and I would like this "internet-free and sandboxed" guest system to be Ubuntu 17.

Comment: Yes very possible

Comment: Just don't create any network devices on the guest VM, make sure you use an up to date ISO and set the deb repo location to the virtual optical drive.

Comment: Yes. Either "remove" the network card(s) from the VM, or put any existing network cards on the "internal only (intnet)" network

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After setting up the Virtual machine go to the settings for that VM and in the network section deselect `Enable Network Adapter` to prevent access to the machine:

[image: Network dialog for VM in VM options]